# Realtime validation of a button, using fody

Tags: xamarin.forms, fody-propertychanged

I a trying to disable and enable a button based on user input. I implemented fody property changed Nuget package, to help me reduce my code a bit.

and it works, when I start typing, the breakpoint in my LoginViewModel gets hit and display my values  [ViewModel getting hit every time I type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zv4D5.png)

but I can't seem to trigger CanLogin() method

```
   [AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
    public class LoginPageViewModel {

        public ICommand OpenRegisterPopupCommand { get; set; }

        public ICommand Register { get; set; }

        public ICommand Login { get; set; }

        public Users Users { get; set; }

        public bool IsPopUpOpen { get; set; }

        public LoginPageViewModel() {

            Users = new Users();

            Login = new Command(LoginAction, CanLogin);

            Register = new Command(RegisterAction);

            OpenRegisterPopupCommand = new Command(() => {
                IsPopUpOpen = true;
            });
        }

        private void LoginAction(object obj) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private bool CanLogin(object arg) {
            if (Users != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Users.Email) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Users.Password)) {

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Recheck the if statement of CanLogin. I make a simple code to check. The CanLogin should return true. Have you check the command. Does it been invoked correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `Command` with a `CanExecute` method. If the `CanExecute` method returns false, the command will not ve able to be executed. But this validation does not happen all the time, you have to trigger it.

You have to call `Login.ChangeCanExecute()` when you modify any of the related properties (like `Users`, `Users.Email` or `Users.Password`),  this will fire the `CanExecute` validation of the command.

[Command documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/commanding#using-command-parameters).

Comment: I was reading the docs but I do not get it, do you mind providing samples. I tried to modify my CanLogin()
`        private bool CanLogin(object arg) {
            if (Users != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Users.Email) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Users.Password)) {

                (Login as Command).ChangeCanExecute(); 
                return true;
            }

            return false;`

please

Comment: I am not familiar with Fody, but normally you would implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to refresh your UI. Usually when you call the `OnPropertyChanged` method asociated, you would call the `Login.ChangeCanExecute()`

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged)... Shouldn't you implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface anyways?

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm#commanding-with-viewmodels) are some examples that explain a little better when to call `ChangeCanExecute`. These examples do not use Fody, but maybe you can get the idea

Comment: Then I guess it is added when being compiled. I don't know if you can suscribe to any fody OnPropertyChanged event. In case you cannot, then you should look for a workaround. Maybe making the validation inside the command (but the button will always show as enabled)

Comment: What I know is that everytime I type I can get the values email  and passwor from the users